# translating one string pattern into another string pattern using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have my source XML like below

```
<contents>
  <content>AuthorInformation</content>
  <content>PersonInformation</content>
  <content>PersonPersonalInformation</content>
  <content>GurdianDetails</content>
</contents>
```

I would like to transform above XML into

```
<contents>
  <content>Author Information</content>
  <content>Person Information</content>
  <content>Person Personal Information</content>
  <content>Gurdian Details</content>
</contents>
```

wherever in source xml file content element data is having upper case letter I would like to prefix space inbetween. Can I have the XSLT 2.0 sample how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1 $2')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This generically performs the rule for all text content in the input. You could easily make this more specific (if there are other elements that you don't want to translate). The `replace` function is the key point.